# Как найти последовательность в списке a, состоящую из k значений в любом порядке из второго списка b?

Tags: python

Как найти в первом списке (a = [ 12, 43, 65, 101, 234, 26, 558, 534, 301, 65, 65... и т.д.] .... до 700 значений) последовательность 8 значений в любом порядке из второго списка (b = [ 48, 73, 101, 558, 43, 303... и т.д.] ... до 20 значений)?

Нужно найти только последовательность, разбросанные поштучные совпадения из 1-3 значений не интересуют.

Comment: @UnbornVs

1. Задаем курсоры `i` и `j` для каждого из массивов (в начале они будут равны нулям, конечно).
2. Итерируем `a` и сравниваем каждый элемент с элементом `b[j]`. Если совпадает, то увеличваем `j` на единицу, если нет - сбрасываем на ноль.
3. Проверяем `j`, если он вышел за границы массивы `b` (стал равен `len(b)`), значит, найдено полное совпадение, которое начинается на элементе `i - j + 1`

Comment: @Etki: в условии сказано *"в любом порядке"* (шаг 2 недостаточен) и `len(b)` может отличаться от `8` (шаг 3 не верен).

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти 8 значений из набора `b`, которые идут *подряд* в списке `a`:

```
k = 8
bset = frozenset(b)
for i in range(len(a) - k + 1):
    if bset.issuperset(a[i:i+k]):
       print("Found {seq} at {i}".format(seq=a[i:i+k], i=i))
       break
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Дупликаты разрешены, например, если одно значение из `b` повторяется 8 раз подряд в `a`, то считается что последовательность найдена.

Сложность алгоритма `O(n*k)`. Учитывая, что `n` и `k` маленькие, не имеет смысла усложнять код ради скорости.