# Как найти данную последовательность в массиве чисел?

Tags: python, python-2.x, список

Нужно в Python 2.4 проверить наличие последовательности данных в списке
Т.е.

```
a=list(10,20,30,40,50)
```

и нужно внутри него найти последовательность `10 20 30`, к примеру и вернуть индекс первого элемента.

Comment: [2.4](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4/), говорите? Внатуре из 2004 года? Какой ужас

Comment: Связанный вопрос - [Как найти последовательность в списке?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/362485/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: 2.4 , да . Но деваться не куда,

Comment: см. [`list_find(what, where)` функцию](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3847960/4279) из связанного вопроса [Testing if a list contains another list with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3847386/4279) можете сравнить её аналог [`index(subseq, seq)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/426168/4279) с производительностью [реализации Knuth-Morris-Pratt алгоритма](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117214/), упомянутого в [Best Way To Determine if a Sequence is in another sequence in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/425604/4279) в вашем случае

Comment: `list(10,20,30,40,50)` это ошибка. (list принимает только один аргумент). Вы хотели `[10,20,30,40,50]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_comparer(data, sub_data):
    i_data = iter(sub_data)
    for i, a in enumerate(data):
        try:
            if a == next(i_data):
                continue
            else:
                i_data = iter(sub_data)
        except StopIteration:
            return i - len(sub_data) 

a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
b = [30, 40]
print list_comparer(a, b)
```

Comment: Подсказки по типам появились в 3.5 - [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) или в более раннем виде в 3.0 - [PEP-3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Comment: Также не очень похоже, чтобы в 2.4 был enumerate - https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/genindex.html#letter-e - в оглавлении нету такого. Как и next, iter - их тоже нету в индексе. Оно точно работает на 2.4?

Comment: Я вру - все это вроде есть. enumerate - [PEP 279](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) - Py2.3. next + iter - [PEP 234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) 2.1