# list index out of range при поиске в списке подпоследовательности подряд идущих элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день подскажите в чем проблема? есть задача определить в списке последовательность 1, 2, 3. Я додумался только до этого:

```
  def listCheck(nums):

    for i in nums:
            if (nums[i] == 1) and (nums[i + 1] == 2) and (nums[i + 2] == 3):
                    return True
    return False

  lists = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4]

  print(listCheck(lists))[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 11, 4]
```

Если в списке list присутствуют числа больше 6, то вылетает ошибка

IndexError: list index out of range

Вопрос чем вызвана данная ошибка?

Comment: Как вы думаете вот тут - `for i in nums:` какие значения получает i ?

Comment: Спасибо понял , добавил переменную j, и использовал её в условие, все заработало как нужно

Comment: связанный вопрос [Best way to determine if a sequence is in another sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425604/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как найти данную последовательность в массиве чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643170/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл надо делать, не доходя двух шагов до длины списка, иначе i+2 вызовет ошибку.

Поэтому цикл должен выглядеть так:

```
def listCheck(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums))[0:-2]:
```

А вообще, a бы делал так:

```
def listCheck(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums))[0:-2]:
    if [1,2,3] == nums[i:i+3]:
      return True
  return False
```

Или так

```
listCheck = lambda s: (1,2,3) in zip(s,s[1:],s[2:])
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, буду обдумывать)

Comment: Удачи!  Там не сложно

Comment: @Yaroslav я там подумал и еще упростил. Я просто не пишу на питоне, поэтому перестраховываюсь :)

Comment: А у `range(len(nums))[0:-2]` есть какие-то преимущества по сравнению с `range(len(nums)-2)`? Что-нибудь со списком короче 3 элементов?

Comment: @Qwertiy если срез используется, то IndexError не будет: `any(lst[i:i+3] == [1,2,3] for i in range(len(lst)))`. Можно сравнить с [`index(subseq, seq)` реализацией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426168/4279)

Comment: @jfs, я ж вычел 2.

Comment: @Qwertiy: я к тому, что не нужно ни `[0:-2]` ни `len(nums) - 2` здесь. У автора вопроса ошибка так используется `nums[i+1]` индексация, а для среза `nums[i:i+3]` не нужно вычитать ничего.

Comment: @jfs, а, понял.

Comment: @jfs Две лишних иттерации

Comment: @splash58 По сравнению с квадратичным алгоритмом это пренебрежимо. Не занимайтесь преждевременными микрооптимизациями.

Comment: Не знаю. Написать срез несложно. Понятней при чтении, что делаем. Нет? А в смысле оптимизации конечно, проку мало